# Google Chrome Portable's Extension is being reset

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, extension

I have my own extension and apply in my Chrome Portable without any user logged.
But when I copy the Chrome Portable folder to another machine and launch the browser, the extension is lost, somehow is like a fresh start.
But I have check the local path of the extension is still there.

How can I keep the extension whenever I copy the folder to another machine to use other than sync to a user?

Comment: Is either machine connected to an active directory domain with the Chromium Administrator policy templates loaded?

Comment: There is no any policy made. I just self made a extension and upload to google store as private. Then I install it to my machine and it work fine every time I launched the portable chrome. But when I copy and paste the portable chrome folder to other machine and use it, it become fresh start ask for login etc as well as the extension is lost.

Answer (score 0):

Currently chrome portable works differently from any other portable browser because it only stores extension by login using google account, not possible by local account only and if u are using different machine then you have to relogin again.

I recommend using firefox portable, because it did stores everything including extension even after being copied to different machine without need to login into firefox account.